# How to Calculate Accuracy %

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, statistics

I have the following scenario.  I have a game in Unity where a player is provided with varying amount of targets (we'll say 125 as an example).  The accuracy is multi-class in that there is Perfect(bullseye), Great, Good, Miss (where miss is the target is missed entirely, no points awarded).  I'm trying to find the right way to calculate a correct accuracy percentage in this scenario.  If the player hits every target (125) as Perfect, the accuracy would be 100%.  If they hit 124 Perfect and 1 Great, while every target was hit the accuracy percentage would still drop (99.8%).  What would be the correct way to calculate this?  Balanced Accuracy? Weighted Accuracy?  Precision?

I'd like to understand the underlying calculation, not just how to implement this in code.

I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: Give accuracy ranks weights... Then max would be hits times max weight fx 125 x 15 (for perfect's weight = 15)... You should find best weights which will fit your needs (fx 15, 10, 5 or something not linear like 15, 8, 1)

Comment: Hehe 15, 8, 1 is almost linea, too.... Maybe 15, 5, 1 or y=x^2 => 9, 4, 1

Comment: Is your measurement hit/miss.  Or does the user get some credit for close (if it's a classic target with rings, is a "bulls eye" the center, and the first ring, not as good, but better than a complete miss.  Then, do you want to make it so that you have a _moving average_; that a recent miss is going to count more than a miss a long time ago.  That's all up to you

Comment: @Flydog57 This is exactly what I have.  If you picture a target with Perfect as the bullseye, Great would be the next ring, then Good.  After that you would miss the target entirely.  If I throw 125 darts, and they land in various places on the target, at the end of the game I'm looking for an overall accuracy %.  However I don't know that a moving average would work in this case because the results have to be restricted to a range someone between 0 and 1, where 1 would be all 125 darts hit the bullseye.

Comment: Just assign a weight to each ring and add things up.  Call the center 16, the next ring 8 (half as much), the next 4, then 2, then 1.  Zero for a miss.  Then add everything up (so, if there are 100 throws, take the sum and divide by 1600).  Don't forget to work in float or double-land; integer division will leave you confused

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying.

Comment: So in the above example, say I assign the weights of 0 = miss, 1 = Good, 2 = Great, and 3 = Perfect then my total possible would be 125 * 3 = 375.  Then to calculate the accuracy % I would take ((3*0) + (5*1) + (90*2) + (27*3)) / 375 = 0.7093 or 70.93% accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be calculated by assigning each accuracy a score between 0 and 100 (percentage) and then calculating the average score or [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) for all the shots.

You could use an enum to define the scores for the different accuracies.

```
public enum Accuracy
{
    Perfect = 100,
    Great = 80,
    Good = 50,
    Miss = 0
}
```

Then to calculate the average you just need to sum all the accuracy scores together and divide the result by the total number of shots.

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(Accuracy shot in shotsTaken)
{
    sum += (int)shot;
}

double average = (double)sum / shotsTaken.Count;
```

Calculating the average can be simplified using [System.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average).

```
public class Tally
{
    private readonly List<Accuracy> shotsTaken = new List<Accuracy>();

    public void RecordShot(Accuracy shot) => shotsTaken.Add(shot);

    public string CalculateAverageAccuracy() => shotsTaken.Average(shot => (int)shot).ToString("0.#") + "%";
}
```

You can test the results using this code:

```
[MenuItem("Test/Tally")]
public static void Test()
{
    var tally = new Tally();
    for(int i = 0; i < 124; i++)
    {
        tally.RecordShot(Accuracy.Perfect);
    }
    tally.RecordShot(Accuracy.Great);
    Debug.Log(tally.CalculateAverageAccuracy());
}
```

Result:

[image]